# Android: Array out of index error while deleting files using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have built a gallery which has options to select multiple items and delete. I am loading images to `GridView` using custom `BaseAdapter` and while deleting I am using `AsyncTask`. But if try to delete multiple items getting array out of bound exception.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index x, size is x
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.android.Example.Adapters.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:94)
```

I am getting this error only when if I use `AsynTask`, Deleting works fine if I do it in main thread.

I have no clue at which point my `ArrayList` is going out of bound.

This my Custom BaseAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader imageLoader;
 private Context mContext;
 private int displayWidth;
 private int imageWidth;
 private ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths

 public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> f) {
    mContext = c;
    this.f=f;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) c).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    imageWidth=(displayWidth/3);
   }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return this.f.size();
   }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.f.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageWidth));
        imageView.setPadding(Utils.dpToPx(2), Utils.dpToPx(2), Utils.dpToPx(2), Utils.dpToPx(2));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setCropToPadding(true);
        imageView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gridview_selector));
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    //imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageLoader.displayImage("file:///"+this.f.get(position),imageView,); //This is line number 94
    return imageView;
}


}
```

And this how I am deleting.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
      ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
      SparseBooleanArray checked = gridView.getCheckedItemPositions();
      int checkedItemCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.delete:
                   new DeleteAsync(checked, checkedItemCount).execute();
                   return true;
```

And this my `AsyncTask`

```
 private class DeleteAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    SparseBooleanArray _checked;
    int _checkedItemCount;

    private DeleteAsync(SparseBooleanArray _checked, int _checkedItemCount) {
        this._checked = _checked;
        this._checkedItemCount = _checkedItemCount;
    }


 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = (_checkedItemCount - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            if (_checked.valueAt(i)) {

                File file = new File(files.get(_checked.keyAt(i)));
                if (file.delete()) {
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{file.toString()}, null, null);
                    files.remove(_checked.keyAt(i));
                } else
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.delete_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        super.onPostExecute(void);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Setting `adapter` to `GridView`

```
   ArrayList<String> files=getListOfImagFiles();
   imageAdapter= new ImageAdapter(rootView.getContext(), files);
   gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Comment: You are passing a list of files as an ArrayList reference to the ImageAdaptor constructor. If this list is modified (i.e items added or deleted) outside of the ImageAdaptor, it will affect the ArrayList inside the adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of array before deleting.
Something like this may work.

```
 if(items.size())>0
for (int i = _checkedItemCount; i > 0; i--) 
{

//do your stuff
}
```

Comment: That part of a code not causing any problem. The problem is onPostExecute where i am calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in getView of gridview adapters. For safe side I have followed like this.

put a condition check in getView()

```
if(position<this.f.size()) 
{
     imageLoader.displayImage("file:///"+this.f.get(position),imageView,); //This is line number 94
}
else
{
   //Display some default img or error img.
}
```

Suggestion:

Do not delete items of array based on the position of item. Delete based on the item model object.

Follow MVC guidelines.

Comment: I solved it in almost similar way but I feel there should be a more prolific way of doing this..

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is giving issue as

1. When you start you have total 10 items in files list. So index will be 0-9 and your for loop runs for this index range.
2. Now when you delete entry from files arraylist your count decreases by one i.e. it becomes Now you index range will be 0-8.
3. So as you go on deleting items from files arraylist your this line of code

   imageLoader.displayImage("file:///"+this.f.get(position),imageView,);

inside baseadapter will loose that position.

So you are left with two options:

1. Do not delete from files arraylist just keep track of filenames and in onpostexecute delete those items from files arraylist and use notifydatasetchanged on your baseadapter.
2. Delete item from files arraylist but on each deletion use onprogressupdate to call notifydatasetchanged on your baseadapter.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try this and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly I solved my problem just putting safe guard before loading image.

```
 if(position<getCount())
     imageLoader.displayImage("file:///"+this.f.get(position),imageView,options);
```

I am not accepting my answer as I think this is not the perfect solution for this problem and also I have no idea why this is happening only when I am using `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Do setAdapter again instead of NotifyDataSetChanged, it will reload the list and position will be correct.